# SQL Server Data Base performance

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have a database low performance problem that occurs everyday at 2pm. I think the problem is caused by a process from an user application that is using the database.

Is there any script that shows who and what is running on the database?

Comment: This query show all users info, or just loged user's info? Do I need any special permission to use this script ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have one for you

```
SELECT sqltext.TEXT,
    req.session_id,
    req.status,
    req.command,
    req.cpu_time,
    req.total_elapsed_time,
    u.name as UserName,
    d.name as DatabaseName,
    Wait_type,
    Wait_time,
    Wait_resource,
    req.Blocking_session_id,Granted_query_memory
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests req
join sys.sysusers u on req.user_id=u.uid
join sys.databases d on d.database_id = req.database_id
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS sqltext
```